# Turn floats to integers in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a fast way to turn floats that are actually integers, to integers in python? For example: `2.0*x+3.1`, I would like to appear as `2*x+3.1`. I could loop through the numbers in the expression and check one by one `if x = int(x)` and then replace them (or something like that), but I was wondering if there is a faster, built-in method to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: The logical way to go would be to give integers as input. Sympy is really unhappy working with floats.

Comment: @JohanC I am not giving the input. That comes from a prewritten code. I want to turn those floats to int for the next step of what I need to do with the expression.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this. You could `nsimplify(expr, rational=True)` but that will change the 3.1 to 31/10 and then you would have to undo that. The use of `replace` does not replace thing which are tested as equal. So the only one-pass solution that I know of is a custom function:

```
>>> def intify(expr):
...  floats = S(expr).atoms(Float)
...  ints = [i for i in floats if int(i) == i]
...  return expr.xreplace(dict(zip(ints, [int(i) for i in ints])))
...
>>> intify(2.0*x+3.1)
2*x + 3.1
```